# Delete span tag along with text in html permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project having a lot of page numbers marked across span class.
Example

```html
<p>Cillacepro di to tem endelias eaquunto maximint eostrum eos dolorit et laboria estiati buscia ditiatiis il et et quia autatemolore sus eum rernatur sequid quam lam con nihillatem ipsus dipsum ute simus.<span class=”pagenum”><a name=”Page_4” id=”Page_4”>[Pg 4]</a></span>Cillacepro di to tem endelias eaquunto maximint eostrum eos dolorit et laboria estiati buscia ditiatiis il et et quia autatemolore sus eum rernatur sequid quam lam con nihillatem ipsus dipsum ute simus.</p>
```

I am looking for a solution which can "delete" the whole span class pagenum syntax such that when I open the HTML file in Microsoft Word, it does not display **[pg 4]** in the text. 
It is a long document of 1000+ pages and deleting span class manually with text through Find feature in Word will take a heck lot of time.
Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("p span.pagenum").remove();` It will remove all `span` with the class `pagenum`.

**demo**

```js
$("p span.pagenum").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Cillacepro di to tem endelias eaquunto maximint eostrum eos dolorit et laboria estiati buscia ditiatiis il et et quia autatemolore sus eum rernatur sequid quam lam con nihillatem ipsus dipsum ute simus.<span class="pagenum"><a name="Page_4" id="Page_4">[Pg 4]</a></span>Cillacepro
  di to tem endelias eaquunto maximint eostrum eos dolorit et laboria estiati buscia ditiatiis il et et quia autatemolore sus eum rernatur sequid quam lam con nihillatem ipsus dipsum ute simus.</p>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. You help is much appreciated. I had already tried this approach and it works wonders for the html file but the moment I open the .html format file in Microsoft Word, those page numbers come back. Therefore, I am looking for a solution that could delete the whole syntax along with the associated text. Thanks a lot for taking out the time to reply.

Comment: @AmanMittal Should like you need to edit the entire html page.

Comment: Yes! As mentioned earler, there are more than 100 pagenum span class which I ould like to remove at a single go such that it completely removes the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it 'manually' with one replace-find using Regex (for example: search for `\[([a-zA-Z0-9-\s]+)\]` and replace with `' '` ).
You can do this in any text editor that supports regex search and replace (atom, sublime, vscode ...)

Comment: Thank you for taking out the time to reply to the question. Much appreciated! I Shall try this approach as this is something I have tried myself. Thanks a lot! Will post the results, soon.

Comment: Is this the right way to search string: <span class=”pagenum”><a name=”Page_\d” id=”Page_\d”>[Pg \d]</a></span>

Comment: I am trying to use Regex in Notepad ++.If possible, you could provide me with the replace string for <span class="pagenum"><a name="Page_1" id="Page_1">[Pg 1]</a></span> such that it could find all such patterns, even, for 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple and clear with jquery script:

```
$("p span").remove();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. You help is much appreciated. I had already tried this approach and it works wonders for the html file but the moment I open the .html format file in Microsoft Word, those page numbers come back. Therefore, I am looking for a solution that could delete the whole syntax along with the associated text. Thanks a lot for taking out the time to reply.

Comment: I don't see why he should upvote it just because it might not be wrong, what if its not right, should he then downvote? @therichpost

Comment: First of how can you tell if I only "down"?? Second I'm asking for your logic about the up and downvote, since up and downvote are used to help other people know what answers helped or not. Sounds like you care more about getting rep, than actual helping.